# Arch ISO not recognizing SSD, does see HDD

Tags: arch-linux, partition, fdisk, parted, cfdisk

I'm installing Arch Linux and when I was about to partition my drives, I noticed something odd. In my laptop, I have two disks: a 1TB HDD and a 512 GB SSD. I would prefer to use the SSD as my boot disk, but fdisk, cfdisk, and parted are only showing my HDD and the flash drive I'm using to install Arch. My UEFI *is* showing it, so there shouldn't be physical problems with the drive, especially since I literally just used it to boot Windows. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and its a laptop so I can't just unplug the drive. Please help!

EDIT: My UEFI is showing the HDD first in the list of devices, does that make a difference?

Comment: Can you post the output of the `lsblk` command?

Answer (score 1):

It is a common problem now a days, check your bios, the SSD is in RAID. Remove that and you are good to go.

Comment: Can you say anything about _why_ it is configured in a RAID configuration by default and whether disabling this in BIOS may have _any other consequences_ (for example, to any other operating system on a dual-booting machine)?

Comment: I can't explain in detail, but now a days most of hybrid storage in laptops comes with [firmware RAID aka fake RAID](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=245829). One can also install linux by installing with [Fake RAID](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_with_Fake_RAID). I will dig into it and come back with a better answer.

Comment: So a note about this actually disabling "hybrid storage" seems to be in order.

Comment: @SakibFarhad Still waiting on that better answer